Powershell Parameter Set with switch not working
I am trying to create a script using parameter sets with a switch parameter.
The variables below should always be required - $Domain, $CohesityVip, $Source, $SourceDbName, $UserName
Optional Parameter - $RestoreTo
If the switch "$AlternateLocation" is supplied the following variables should be required -
$Target, $TargetDbName, $MdfFolder, $LdfFolder
When I specify the "$AlternateLocation" switch, the other parameters do not prompt for value
Scenario 1 Works

PS C:\temp\Cohesity Restore Script> .\Test.ps1 -Domain Domain1 -CohesityVip VIP1 -Source SQL1 -SourceDbName DB1 -UserName MyUserName

Output below

./restoreSQL.ps1 -vip VIP1 -username MyUserName -domain Domain1 -sourceServer SQL1 -sourceDB DB1

Scenario 2 does not work. Provide the "$AlternateLocation". Should be prompted for Target, TargetDbName, MdfFolder, LdfFolder

PS C:\temp\Cohesity Restore Script> .\Test.ps1 -Domain Domain1 -CohesityVip VIP1 -Source SQL1 -SourceDbName DB1 -UserName MyUserName -AlternateLocation

Output below

./restoreSQL.ps1 -vip VIP1 -username MyUserName -domain Domain1 -sourceServer SQL1 -sourceDB DB1

Here is the script
    param (
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("Domain1", "Domain2","Domain3")][string]$Domain,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("VIP1", "VIP2")][string]$CohesityVip,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Source,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SourceDbName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$true)]
    [switch]$AlternateLocation,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Target,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$TargetDbName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$MdfFolder,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$LdfFolder,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory=$false)]
    [hashtable]$NdfFolders,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Datetime]$RestoreTo, 
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $UserName
    )


$restoreCmd = "./restoreSQL.ps1 -vip ${CohesityVip} -username ${UserName} -domain ${Domain} -sourceServer ${Source} -sourceDB ${SourceDbName}"


#Target location
if($AlternateLocation.IsPresent){

$restoreCmd += " -targetServer ${Target} -targetDB ${TargetDbName} -mdfFolder ${MdfFolder} -ldfFolder ${LdfFolder}"

    if($NdfFolders){
        $restoreCmd += " -ndfFolders ${NdfFolders}"
    }
}


Write-Output $restoreCmd

Any help appreciated

A switch is never supposed to be Mandatory for reference. It's counter intuitive.

I got the code below to work as expected
    param (
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet("Domain1", "Domain2","Domain3")][string]$Domain,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet("VIP1", "VIP2")][string]$CohesityVip,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory)]
    [string]$Source,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory)]
    [string]$SourceDbName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target')]
    [switch]$AlternateLocation,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [string]$Target,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [string]$TargetDbName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory)]
    [string]$MdfFolder,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory)]
    [string]$LdfFolder,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Target',Mandatory=$false)]
    [hashtable]$NdfFolders,
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Datetime]$RestoreTo, 
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Source', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter (ParameterSetName='Target', Mandatory)]
    [string] $UserName
    )


$restoreCmd = "./restoreSQL.ps1 -vip ${CohesityVip} -username ${UserName} -domain ${Domain} -sourceServer ${Source} -sourceDB ${SourceDbName}"


#Target location
if($AlternateLocation.IsPresent){

$restoreCmd += " -targetServer ${Target} -targetDB ${TargetDbName} -mdfFolder ${MdfFolder} -ldfFolder ${LdfFolder}"

    if($NdfFolders){
        $restoreCmd += " -ndfFolders ${NdfFolders}"
    }
}


Write-Output $restoreCmd


Here, it's easier to read.
__AllPatrameterSet is the hidden name of the parameter set used when a ParameterSet name is not set and thus a parameter is available in every Parameter Set
Note: ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace() is available only in Powershell 7.4+
You might want to use ValidateNotNullOrEmpty() otherwise.
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = '__AllParameterSets')]
param (
    # Parameters are available in every set
    [Parameter ( ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('Domain1', 'Domain2', 'Domain3')][string]$Domain,

    [Parameter ( ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('VIP1', 'VIP2')][string]$CohesityVip,

    [Parameter (ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$Source,

    [Parameter ( ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$SourceDbName,
    
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string] $UserName,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName )]
    [Datetime]$RestoreTo,


    # Parameters are available only in the 'Target' parameter set
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target', Mandatory)]
    [switch]$AlternateLocation,

    [Parameter (ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$Target,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$TargetDbName,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$MdfFolder,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target', Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()][string]$LdfFolder,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Target')]
    [hashtable]$NdfFolders

    
    
)

PS > get-command ./restoreSQL.ps1 -Syntax
    ./restoreSQL.ps1 -Domain <string> -CohesityVip <string> -Source <string> -SourceDbName <string> -UserName <string> [-RestoreTo <datetime>] [<CommonParameters>]
    ./restoreSQL.ps1 -Domain <string> -CohesityVip <string> -Source <string> -SourceDbName <string> -UserName <string> -AlternateLocation -Target <string> -TargetDbName <string> -MdfFolder <string> -LdfFolder <string> [-RestoreTo <datetime>] [-NdfFolders <hashtable>] [<CommonParameters>]

